# Wordpress permalinks: only using the post_id from the URL

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, seo, permalinks

I'm trying to have SEO friendly URLs for my wordpress blog, while still having the flexibility to change a post's title at will.

My permalink structure would be like this:

> %post_id%/%postname%

However, I'd like wordpress to just consider the %post_id% from the URL when looking for the appropriate post (sort of like here on stackoverflow)

For example:

**https://stackoverflow.com/users/810/crossbrowser** is the same as **https://stackoverflow.com/users/810/hello-world**

I'd like all of these to point to the same post, the one with id 345:

```
http://myblog.com/345/the-name-of-the-post
http://myblog.com/345/any-text
http://myblog.com/345
```

---

The documentation mentions something that seems like what I'm trying to do: [Long permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Long_Permalinks), but I couldn't get it to work.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Let wordpress use pretty permalinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# From the example in the documentation
#RewriteRule /post/([0-9]+)?/?([0-9]+)?/?$ /index.php?p=$1&page=$2 [QSA]
```

---

**UPDATE**

I keep trying this RewriteRule in this [online regular expression testing tool](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/), but it doesn't work when I put it in my .htaccess (just after RewriteBase):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My response does not directly answer your question, but I think I have some points worth noting.

> I'm trying to have SEO friendly URLs
>   for my wordpress blog, while still
>   having the flexibility to change a
>   post's title at will.

I'm not immediately seeing the benefit of your pursuit.

The obvious disadvantage of including the %post_id% is that it makes the URL longer and contains non-semantic information. Wordpress already deals with the scenario in two ways:

1. The url (permalink/post name) doesn't change when you change the title on a published post.
2. If you do change the permalink, the old permalink continues to work and redirects to the new permalink.

Comment: I want to change title because I tend to rethink my titles sometimes and in those cases, I just need to change the permalink (my little OCD side).

If #2 is true though, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)(/[^/]*)?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I don’t know if the substituion is correct. You have to check that by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

By using this [tool](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/), I was able to build an expression that matches everything in my list:

```
http://myblog.com/435
http://myblog.com/435/the-post-title
http://myblog.com/435/the-po
http://myblog.com/435/asdf
http://myblog.com/435/the-9887-title
http://myblog.com/435/123
```

The expression is:

```
http://myblog.com/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?
```

which would translate to this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

however, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I almost got it working by using this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)?/?(^/+)?/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [QSA]

# Allow pretty permalinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

however, it doesn't always work and I'm not sure I understand why (or why it should work)

It works with these:

```
http://myblog.com/435
http://myblog.com/435/the-post-title
http://myblog.com/435/the-po
```

but not with any of these:

```
http://myblog.com/435/asdf (when there's no dash)
http://myblog.com/435/the-9887-title (whenever there's a number in the post title)
```

Any help?

Comment: You should use canonical URIs.

Comment: Only your PHP app could do that as only it can obtain the entry title when just the ID is given.