# how to changes url in wordpress from page id to postname?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, permalinks

i want to change url from

**example.com/abc/?page_id=1** to

**example.com/postname**.

i tried different methods but there is some issue ....on screen error occurring which is ***not found url not found in server*** what should i do ..i change my permalink , .htaccess files etc. my htaccess file is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/projects/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /abc/projects/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I tried `permalink` option also

Comment: Just FYI. You do realize that you have just revealed that this project is for a big real estate developer in Mumbai. Make sure you clean up your code before submitting again.  Edit: Removed developer's name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress permalinks: only using the post\_id from the URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553767/wordpress-permalinks-only-using-the-post-id-from-the-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read more about wordpress. This is already available in wordpress setting.

1. Go to Admin section -> Setting -> Permalinks.
2. change the comman setting to Post name and save the changes.

Comment: i already done this but on browser showing error"this page not found on this server"....what i should do?

Comment: Go to the permalink there you can find data for .htaccess. just copy those and paste on the main root folder.

Comment: i already done this .... i have two htaccess file one in root folder and another in word-press folder, so where to put and what about templete?